Trying to implement a barrier for pthreads in C++ using pthread condition variables and mutexes
I am currently trying to implement a barrier to control a group of threads. Te barrier class needs a constructor, destructor, and the wait method which I believe I have already created correcty. The thread function is to demonstrate what the class does to the threads by printing which threads are behind the barrier which barrier it was the printing that each thread passed the barrier. When I run the program, it stops printing the statements after the first instance of passing the barrier and only prints the last thread that reached the barrier. Here is the code:
// barrier.cc
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

class Barrier {
public:
    explicit Barrier(int num_threads) : num_threads(num_threads), count(0), waiting(0) {
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, nullptr);
        pthread_cond_init(&cond, nullptr);
    }

    ~Barrier() {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    }

    void wait() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        ++waiting;
        if (waiting == num_threads) {
            waiting = 0; // Reset waiting count for the next barrier
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond); // Unblock all threads
        } else {
            while (waiting < num_threads) {
                pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            }
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

private:
    int num_threads;
    int count;
    int waiting;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
};

// Example function to be run by threads
void* threadFunction(void* arg) {
    Barrier* barrier = static_cast<Barrier*>(arg);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread " << pthread_self() << " at barrier " << i << std::endl;
        barrier->wait();
        std::cout << "Thread " << pthread_self() << " passed barrier " << i << std::endl;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    const int num_threads = 5;
    pthread_t threads[num_threads];
    Barrier barrier(num_threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], nullptr, threadFunction, &barrier);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], nullptr);
    }

    return 0;
}


I tried changing the loop and was unsuccessful in threadfunction. I am unsure of what needs to be changed for the program to work. I want the program to continue printing until the program is exited by the user.

Why are you using pthreads in C++ in 2024 rather than std::threads?

Once the first therad encounters waiting == num_threads and sets waiting = 0 the others will not get past while (waiting < num_threads) anymore. And because then you have all the threads waiting but waiting is 1 they all get stuck. You need to distinguish between threads still waiting on the last barrier and threads already waiting on the next barrier for this to work.

As long as you're using pthreads, you do know that it already provides a barrier, right?

Here is a running case for why your program get stuck.



waiting (initial = 0)
T1
T2
T3
T4
T5




1
T1 wait






2

T2 wait





3


T3 wait




4



T4 wait



0




reset and notify T1~4


1




T5 wait


1
T1 wait again because waiting < 5







You can use another counter to record different barrier waiting round to resolve this problem.
class Barrier {
public:
    explicit Barrier(int num_threads) : num_threads(num_threads), count(0), waiting(0), round(0) {
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, nullptr);
        pthread_cond_init(&cond, nullptr);
    }

    ~Barrier() {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    }

    void wait() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        int wait_round = round;
        ++waiting;
        if (waiting == num_threads) {
            waiting = 0; // Reset waiting count for the next barrier
            round++; // update waiting round
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond); // Unblock all threads
        } else {
            while ((waiting < num_threads) && (wait_round == round)) {
                pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            }
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

private:
    int num_threads;
    int count;
    int waiting;
    int round;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
};

